# /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, capistrano

I have the problem. I've installed rvm but when I try to `cap deploy:setup` I have:

```
bash: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory
    command finished in 244ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p0' -c 'mkdir -p /srv/xxx /srv/xxx/releases /srv/xxx/shared /srv/xxx/shared/system /srv/xxx/shared/log /srv/xxx/shared/pids'" on xxxxxxxx
```

I've tried to `cd` to `/usr/local/rvm` but I have `No such file or directory`. How to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
set :default_shell, "/bin/bash -l"
```

works for me

Answer (score 5):

works for me:

```
set :rvm_type, :user
```

before it check where is your rvm-shell.
run on server:

```
which rvm-shell
```

If you will see something like /home/mihserf/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell then try the solution pointed above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [ubuntu rvm package](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm) add need to add `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` to the bottom of your .bashrc file.

Comment: I wound up doing this
`sudo ln -s /usr/share/rvm/ /usr/local/rvm`

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned by @Strik3r follow documentation at https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme and add to your `config/deploy.rb`:

```
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_rvm'
```

there are few examples available, most interesting https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#rvm--ruby-on-every-deploy

all the available options are described here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#options

Answer (score 1):

### This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Setting the default shell in your deploy.rb file using:

`set :default_shell, :bash`

**or** selectively in your tasks like this (just an example):

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Install stuff"
  task :install do
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y update", :shell => "sh"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install python-software-properties build-essential, :shell => "sh"
  end
end
```

For more info check the [docs](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#to-control-rvm-shell-manually)