# Got error while deploy rails code on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am getting below error when tried to deploy using `capistrano`

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell - No such file or directory

 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::CommandError, failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-2.0.0-p353' -c 'rm -rf /home/xxx/xxxxxx/releases/20151019095324; true'" on xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Any one have a solution.

Comment: ruby package is not configured on server?

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711361/usr-local-rvm-bin-rvm-shell-no-such-file-or-directory, Hope this will work for you..

Comment: @sushilprj Thanks for link which same error which i ma facing but try that solution which not solved for me. I think rvm not install on server. Is that required for deployment.. i did not get this think.

Comment: I used before 'deploy',  'rvm:install_rvm' in deply.rb file and now get different error... Error: RVM was unable to use 'Ruby-2.0.0-p353'.. what i have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Rvm is probably not installed or not accessible from the user "declared" in capistrano.

Refer to https://rvm.io/rvm/install to check if rvm is correctly installed on your server.

Comment: Yes, i check on server "which rvm-shell" command then got that "no rvm-shell in". what i have to do? Need to install rvm on server?